# How to count the number of words and sentences per string in c?

Tags: c, cs50, readability

Here are the instructions of an exercise that I have to solve for cs50 pset2 readability(copy pasted from the site):

- Your program should count the number of letters, words, and sentences in the text. You may assume that a letter is any lowercase character from a to z or any uppercase character from A to Z, any sequence of characters separated by spaces should count as a word, and that any occurrence of a period, exclamation point, or question mark indicates the end of a sentence.

These are not the complete instructions, just the part I have trouble with.

I figured out how to count the number of letters in the text, but I can't figure out how to count the words and sentences. I've tried googling it and using other external resources, but all that pops up is the answer to the problem, which, frankly, feels like cheating. This is my code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<ctype.h>


int main (void)
{
    int letters = 0;
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int words = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text);i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i]) != 0)
        {
        letters++;
        }
    }
    printf("Letters: %i\n", letters);
    


   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text);i++)
   {
       if (isspace(text[i]) != 0)
       {
          if(isalpha (text[i] + 1) != 0) 
          {
              words++;
          }
       }
 
   }
   
   printf("Words: %i\n", words);
}
```

This code counts the correct number of letters but always types Words : 0. I haven't done the sentences part.  Can I please have some help? If you show me the answer, can you explain why that's the answer?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might show us your code. Then we can tell you were to adjust it.

Comment: Hint: If you found some letters and then you find something not a letter then chances are high that you just found the end of a word and the next letter is starting a new word.

Comment: IMHO this question would maybe be more appropriate at https://math.stackexchange.com/ than on Stack Overflow although programming context because advanced math is more needed than programming art here.

Comment: *"If you down-vote my question, can you tell me why you chose to do so in the comments below?"* - Certainly, and it's good that you want to learn. SO is not intended for tutoring, but for clear question/answer pairs.

Comment: I know from myself asking people to not downvote will result in the opposite here although you do it kindly.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio True enough, but OP did not ask not to DV, but instead to motivate it in comments.

Comment: Also, it seems like you have posted the whole assignment instructions, but you're only looking for help on a tiny bit of it. That is, write a function that takes a string and returns the number of  words. This question could have been a lot shorter, and you should also provide your own attempt to solve it.

Comment: Ok I'll add code and thanks for the help

Comment: And I'll make it simpler too. Thanks a million for helping me learn how to improve my questions and for the advice. I won't forget it.

Comment: Actually, learning how to ask for help is an important and not trivial skill to learn as a programmer :)

Comment: What do you mean with "*I've tried googling it and using other external resources, but all that pops up is the answer to the problem, which, frankly, feels like cheating.*"? This listens to me like you already found an answer (which seems to be wrong).

Comment: @ryyker Yep. ;-) But issue keeps the same.

Comment: I meant that it just gives me the solution to the WHOLE exercise which is cheating since it's just copy - pasting code from the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text);i++)
{
    if (isspace(text[i]) != 0)
    {
       if(isalpha (text[i] + 1) != 0) 
       {
           words++;
       }
    }
}
```

There are some wrong things here. What you need to do is to realize that this program can be in one of two states. Either you are currently reading a word or not.

```
bool reading_word = false; // Flag
int words = 0;

for(int i=0; i<strlen(text); i++) {
    if(isspace(text[i]) {
        reading_word = false;
    }
    else if(isalpha(text[i])) {
        if(!reading_word) {
            reading_word = true;
            words++;
        }
    }
}
```

Plus, don't write `if(isspace(text[i]) != 0)`. It returns a Boolean value, so it's basically meant to be read "if text[i] is a space", so just write `if(isspace(text[i]))`

Also, in your code `isalpha (text[i] + 1)` is completely wrong and makes no sense. Since this is homework, I leave it to you to find out why.

For the sentences, you can use a function like this:

```
int isdelim(char c)
{
    return c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?';
}
```

and then use it in a similar manner as the loop for counting words.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tested it out and it works! Just one thing: can you explain in these comments why your program works but mine didn't? I may need the information later on. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Lostincode Take pen and paper and do manual execution. You can also insert a print statement inside the loop to see the values of all variables at each iteration.

Comment: And also, I don't understand how the sentences thing works. Should I add a int called sentences and then do: ' int isdelim(char c)
{
    return c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?'; sentences ++;
}'?

Comment: By the way, how do you add a new line in comments? Every time I try by pressing ENTER, it just posts the comments.

Comment: You'll have to figure the complete sentence thing out on your own. Asking someone for a complete solution is equally cheating as just copying a solution, just less effective for everyone ;)

Comment: I don't know what a "custom function" is. Can you tell me what it is, cause I can't use your advice until I know what a "custom function" is. Ty.

Comment: @Lostincode - Regarding your question about entering a _new line_ in these comments, you don't.  Just keep typing, it will populate the box until you are done. The return key sends the text